# What is the necessary and sufficient condition of linear dependence of $n$ functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

If $n$ functions are linear dependent, then the Wronskian determinent is zero, While that the Wronskian determinent is zero cannot imply $n$ functions are linear dependent.
So what is the necessary and sufficient condition of linear dependence of $n$ functions?

Comment: Under certains conditions Gramm determinant can be used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things I just grabbed from Wikipedia:

- You're right, the Wronskian does not imply linear independence.  Just consider $x^2$ and $\left |x\right | x$
- However, if $f$ and $g$ are both analytic, the Wronskian does imply linear independence.  This was shown by Peano in 1889
- Additionally, if the Wronskian is $0$ and the $n$ Wronskians of all sets of $n - 1$ of the $n$ functions are $0$, the functions are also linearly independent
- There are other, more general conditions as well, though I don't believe we have found the most general case

And of course, if you have the explicit functions you can do it the hard way: for functions $f_0, f_1, \ldots f_n$, show that it is impossible to write $f_0 = a_1f_1 + a_2f_2 + \ldots + a_nf_n$ for any constants $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n \in F$, where $F$ is whatever field you're working over.

By the way, here's the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian.  You should check that site out a bit ;)  Hope that helped.